# Powershell - Split Array Value keep first element

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, json

I'm trying to extract just the IPs from a filtered JSON using the following code:

```
$curl = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri "http://urltojson.com/file.json"
$curl2 = $curl.Content.replace("Script", "Script_").replace("iphone", "iphone_").replace("android", "android_").replace("ipad","ipad_")  | ConvertFrom-Json
$curl3 = $curl2 | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "/Common/cloudfront_nets"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty data
$curl3
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$curl3[0] = $curl3
$curl3[1]
```

Which returns the following

> 13.59.250.0 255.255.255.192    : region: us-east-2-service: CLOUDFRONT
>
> 52.57.254.0 255.255.255.0      : region: eu-central-1-service: CLOUDFRONT
>
> 54.182.0.0 255.255.0.0         : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT
>
> 52.212.248.0 255.255.255.192   : region: eu-west-1-service: CLOUDFRONT
>
> 205.251.250.0 255.255.254.0    : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT
>
> 35.162.63.192 255.255.255.192  : region: us-west-2-service: CLOUDFRONT
>
> 13.32.0.0 255.254.0.0          : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT
>
> 205.251.254.0 255.255.255.0    : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT

I'm struggling to simply output the IPs (without the subnet-mask)

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
$datas=@"
13.59.250.0 255.255.255.192 : region: us-east-2-service: CLOUDFRONT

52.57.254.0 255.255.255.0 : region: eu-central-1-service: CLOUDFRONT

54.182.0.0 255.255.0.0 : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT

52.212.248.0 255.255.255.192 : region: eu-west-1-service: CLOUDFRONT

205.251.250.0 255.255.254.0 : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT

35.162.63.192 255.255.255.192 : region: us-west-2-service: CLOUDFRONT

13.32.0.0 255.254.0.0 : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT

205.251.254.0 255.255.255.0 : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT
"@


# if you want put the result into an array
$ipv4s = @()


Write-Host ("In loop");
# if file provide from a linux system change `r`n` for `n
([String]$datas).split("`r`n") |% { 

    if($_){

        # adjust index for your choice (here ipv4 addr) at index 0
        [String]$ip     = ([String]$_).split(" ")[0];
        $ipv4s += $ip;

        Write-Host ($ip);
    }

}


Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow ("`r`nTotal IPV4s : " + $ipv4s.Count);
Write-Host ("In array");
$ipv4s | % { write-host $_}
# equivalent
#foreach($ipv4 in $ipv4s){
#    write-host $ipv4;
#}
# You can access to object with index (in range of $ipv4s.Count)
# Write-Host ($ipv4s[0]); Write-Host ($ipv4s[1]); etc...
```

**OUT**

```
In loop
13.59.250.0
52.57.254.0
54.182.0.0
52.212.248.0
205.251.250.0
35.162.63.192
13.32.0.0
205.251.254.0

Total IPV4 : 8
In array
13.59.250.0
52.57.254.0
54.182.0.0
52.212.248.0
205.251.250.0
35.162.63.192
13.32.0.0
205.251.254.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Giving @J-barnaby credit for the first and correct answer, the shorter bit (assuming `$curl3[1]` contains the output data you need formatted) would look like this:

```
# split the text into array of strings on line breaks and filter empty lines
$output = $curl3[1] -split "`r`n" | ? {$_} 

# process each line
$addresses = foreach ($line in $output)
{
    # further break each line into space delimited words, selecting first word
    $line.Split(' ')[0] 
}

# output the resulting list
$addresses
```